# Seaside jQuery - Sorting a list with drag and drop and sending it back via Ajax causes OrderedCollection to turn into an Array?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

The code below is form the Seaside book at: http://book.seaside.st/book/web-20/jquery/enhanced-todo-application/drag-and-drop

```
html jQuery new sortable
    onStop:
            (html jQuery ajax
                    callback: [ :items | modelRole getModelRolePlayer setItemList: items ]
                    passengers: (html jQuery this find: 'li'));
    axis: 'y'
```

My instance variable _itemList is initially OrderedCollection. As soon as I move the rows around in the page then entire list is sent back in it's new order. However, this time setItemList: receives an Array.

Does this make any sense? Am I missing something?

Comment: when you say you have two instances of `TodoItemList`, I guess one of them is in the `Singleton` class variable, right? Where do you find the other one?

Comment: Looks good to me. Spontaneous class change is *very* unlikely. Also, Pharo doesn't react to sleep / wakeup so I hardly think that the problem lies there. Have you checked the senders of `#itemList` and `#itemList:`? Anything there that might explain the change? And yes, where do you see the second instance (Hint: `TodoItemList allInstances explore`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that `#callback:passenger:` uses `#subStrings:` to get the element ids from the AJAX callback and then does a `#collect:` on that collection to determine the Smalltalk objects. Since `#subStrings:` returns an array, the `#collect:` will also return an array.

The solution: send `#asOrderedCollection` to the array before storing it:

```
(html jQuery ajax
  callback: [ :items | modelRole getModelRolePlayer setItemList: items asOrderedCollection ]
  passengers: (html jQuery this find: 'li'));
```

Comment: Great it works :D the example was incomplete... On my way again to finish the book.